# Inverted Amplifier Circuit not working

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

In a nutshell: The below circuit is not working. The signal is distorted and is not amplified. I expect it to be amplified by R_1/R_2.

[image: opamp]

The op-amp is a [TL071](http://www.ti.com/litv/pdf/slos080j).

So my question is, **how do I get this thing to work and how do I debug it?**

Thing's I've tried:

- A resistor approximately (R_1 R_2)/(R_1+R_2) between the third leg and the ground (to cancel out bias current, but it didn't change anything.)
- Grounding one of the power supplies (this did things, but not useful things and I couldn't explain why it should be that way to myself so I changed it back.)
- Changing components and circuit boards.
- Varying sizes of resistors.

[image: Circuit board]

Comment: Too long to read, but SHOW THE CIRCUIT.  We can't tell what exactly you have done without a proper schematic.  Show the schematic, describe what is going in and what is coming out.  Or provide scope traces for those.  Also, whether you are crying or not and how many points you might have elsewhere is irrelevant here.  You will get better help by treating people with respect, which means getting to the point concisely without time-wasting fluff.

Comment: Do you really mean 10 ohms as the feedback resistor R2? Try 1k (-1 gain) or 2k (-2 gain) before anything else. Opamps don't like low impedance loads like 10 ohms. Also : what type of opamp?

Comment: @OlinLathrop Thanks for your feedback. I don't mean disrespect, just not good at this. I added a very short summary bringing up those points and deleted my intro.

Comment: Also : how are you referencing 0V on the schematic to the PSU? You really want it to be Vs/2; you can do this crudely with two identical resistors, one to each supply rail

Comment: @BrianDrummond I tried different sizes but thanks, I will not use those for testing anymore. The OP-AMP I think is TL071, possibly TL071A.

Comment: I bet you would find the information in [Single-Supply Op Amp Design Techniques](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa030a/sloa030a.pdf) useful.

Comment: @calle You might find circuitlab.com a nice place to be able to make a schematic easily. [This circuit](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/evwhmz/inverting-opamp-circuit/) should be a good base circuit for including your voltages.

Comment: I may have missed some info, but how is the circuit "not working" exactly? What is it's purpose? What are the resistor values?

Comment: @OliGlaser I started editing stuff out (by request) and it got lost. I added a short version of it back in at the top.

Comment: @Calle - is your signal centered around 0V? (i.e. does it swing negative with respect to your circuit ground?)

Comment: On your 10V power supply, is it +10V and -10V, or is the "-" pin also connected to ground?

Comment: @OliGlaser Yes, I am not 100% positive but it's a function generator that's set to 1 kHz with a certain amplitude so should think it swings +- amplitude.

Comment: @AndrewKohlsmith the two wires are connected to the DC power supply, which have a contact "+" and a contact "-" and it is set to 10V. None is connected to ground, if you connect the wires to a multimeter it will show 10V.

Comment: @Calle ok, where are you connecting the + pin of the op-amp input? it shows it's connected to a ground (or common) -- the "-" of the 10V supply and the "-" of the sine should be connected together and that node should be called your ground or common.

Comment: @AndrewKohlsmith I did not do that, will try that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few problems here I think:

- You are using a single supply and your input swings negative.
- Your input impedance is too low for your signal generator (determined by R3 which is a low 10Ω - your signal generator output is quite likely 50Ω so it will be loaded heavily by the 10Ω e.g. act like a voltage divider)
- Just noticed your positive supply is connected to the output - I'm assuming this is an accidental error whilst drawing the schematic, but if it isn't it should definitely not be connected.
- One other (potential) problem is the large gain - I just checked the Unity Gain Bandwidth of the [TL071](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl071a.pdf) and it's only 3MHz, so at a gain of 1000 you are looking at a bandwidth of ~3kHz (see [Gain Bandwidth Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gain%E2%80%93bandwidth_product)). If you want a higher bandwidth, then use a second stage and split the gain between them (e.g. 20 * 50 or similar)

If you want to use the inverting configuration with single supply, you need to AC couple your input, use a higher value resistor combination, and tie the positive input to mid-supply:

[image: Circuit Suggestion]

A small cap may be necessary across R2 to prevent oscillations (a few pF). R1 and R5 can be higher for lower current, I just altered a previous circuit and left them like that.

Simulation:

[image: Circuit Simulation]

Comment: It says 10 V on the input where I have the sinus wave. But I just replace it with my sinus wave (which is much lower than the supply voltage)? For the supply voltage, you set one to ground. Does that mean I have to connect the - supply wire to the ground of the circuit board?

Comment: It says 10V at the top of the divider for the *non-inverting input* (+) - you have your sine wave connected to the inverting input (-). It is the same circuit, except for the 5V at the non-inverting input, and the capacitor coupling.

Comment: Yes, connect the - supply wire to your circuit ground.

Comment: It worked wonderfully :)

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to connect power to the opamp.  It would also help to provide the opamp model with a link to the datasheet, and the values of the resistors.

When considering the opamp power requirement, note that it needs negative power if the input ever goes positive.  If the input is always negative, then you can power the opamp from ground and some appropriate positive supply.  Without the opamp model and range of input and desired output voltages, I can't provide any specifics.

### Added in response to your latest schematic:

[image]

This now clearly defines the opamp, the resistor value, and how the input is hooked up.  Those all make sense.  10 kΩ is well within the range this opamp can handle, and with the two resistors being equal you should get a overall gain of -1 centered about ground.

The remaining problem is how the opamp is powered.  First, powering a TL071 with only 10 V doesn't leave much operating room, although it should work for a limited output voltage range.  Look at the datasheet and you will see this opamp can require up to 2.5 V headroom on both power rails relative to what the output can swing if I remember right.  If that is true at 10 V power, then you only have a 5 V or so output range.  Although that is limited and not really how a TL071 is intended to be used, it should still work if you're OK with the limited range.

The real problem with the power is how it is referenced to the rest of the circuit.  Since you want symmetric operation about ground, the power terminals should also be symmetric about ground.  If you want 10 V power, there should really be separate +5V and -5V rails.

Connecting the positive supply to the output is definitely wrong in any case.  From the opamp's point of view, that doesn't allow the output to swing at all, and it can't function as a opamp.  Disconnect the positive supply from the output.  Both supply rails should be referenced to ground, since that's also what both the input and output signal are referenced to.  While you're at it, put 100 nF to 1 µF bypass caps at each power pin to ground.

Another issue is that the TL07x opamps can be a little finnicky at unity gain, despite what the datasheet may claim.  Put a capacitor accross R1 so that it starts to roll off just above the highest frequency you care about.  For example, if this is intended for audio, you can set the rollof around 40 kHz, which would be a octave above the highest frequency of interest.  About 2 nF would do it, and will keep the opamp from going unstable.

### Added 2:

I just noticed that the two resistors are not equal.  R2 is 1000 times less than R1.  This is not a good idea.  Asking for a gain of 1000 from a single opamp stage is pushing it, and unless you have a very small input signal the output will clip.  Get the circuit working with a smaller gain to start with.  You can crank up the gain and see what you can get away with once everything else is working.  Start with R2 at 10 kΩ, for a overall gain of -1.  Or, keep the initial gain during debugging low, like below 10x.  You can make R2 2 kΩ for a gain of -5, but don't try for a higher gain until everything works.

Once you get the circuit working, consider that R2 will be its input impedance.  Lots of sources won't be happy being loaded with 10 Ω.   It would be good to keep R2 at 1 kΩ or higher eventually.  Make R1 higher for higher gain if that's what you really want.

Comment: That schematic excludes the power supply, as does every single one of the op amp schematics in my book on electronics. That is not my problem.

Comment: @Calle: It is still a problem in that the schematic is incorrect. Please respect people's time here and post a schematic OF WHAT YOU ACTUALLY BUILT.  We can only know about your circuit what you tell us.  If you show no power hooked up, then we can only assume no power is hooked up.

Comment: @PhilFrost Most student text books exclude the op amp power connections for readability.

Comment: A schematic without power supplies might be okay for teaching ideal op-amps, but it's not much use for diagnosing a beginners problems.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I added the supply as I think you meant.

Comment: @Calle and what about the signal generator? It's not in the schematic, or the picture. How can we know how you have connected that?

Comment: @PhilFrost I updated my post.