# Simulation of inverting summing amplifier not working and finding it's parameters

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

I have a project to create circuit of inverting summing amplifier with 3 inputs and a simulation on it. I am using capture (OrCAD Pspice) and so far I got to the circuit you see below, at the end of this wall of text. The circuit is supposed to have the following parameters:

```
Av1 = 1
Av2 = 2
Av3 = 3
f max = 20kHz
```

And that's it. Since I do not have the value of any resistors I should use in my circuit I have picked a random number - in my case:

```
Rf = -6k Ohm
Ri1 = 6k Ohm
Ri2 = 3k Ohm
Ri3 = 2k Ohm
```

Please note that I am not even sure that Rf can have negative value, but if it doesn't I am not really sure how I can make the voltage gain positive as the equation is:

```
Av1 = -(Rf/Ri1)
```

The second problem is that I can not get the simulation to work. I am not sure which one should I use (probably the AC sweep?), but I have tried using Time Domain, DC Sweep, AC sweep, Bias points. Not even one of them worked. I tried changing the sources between AC and DC, but I keep getting flat only lines. The only thing that works in my simulation is that with increasing the voltage through resistors their current increases. I am pretty sure the simulation I get should look something like the one shown [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/56458/35801) - I tried to make my circuit diagram pretty much the same to the one in that post, but it still doesn't work.

Here is the diagram itself:
[image]

Comment: I'm getting the impression that both your 12V rails are positive...

Comment: And positive feedback.  And a negative resistor.  Definitely a few things to fix here.

Comment: Compare your circuit to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/58228/how-do-i-calculate-the-gain-of-an-op-amp-summing-amplifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the pin-out of a 741: -

[image]

Please note the following: -

- Positive supply is to pin 7 not pin 5
- Negative supply is to pin 4 not pin 1
- Negative feedback is from output to the inverting input NOT the non-inverting input
- The gain is inverting i.e. the minus sign is associated with the gain being inverted as in +1v becomes -1v therefore Rf is a positive value.

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed my mistakes, but I still can not get any changes in the simulation. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/hbcHciS.png) is how my circuit looks right now - I can see that there is a flowing current as all of the resistors change their voltage (comparing the voltage on both pins), but I can not get the sine wave that I showed in my first post. I have tried getting it on "out2" and "out" (although it should not be there), but still nothing. Do you have any idea what might be the problem? P.S. Do not mind the green circle

Comment: @r0Lf try adjusting the amplitudes - at the moment you will get a massive signal that clips. Set two signals to zero amplitude and adjust one signal to check that it looks ok.

Comment: Apparently the green circle was actually very important - I had to change the element, since there was no information in it for the simulation to work. Thank you!